# CodeIgniter converting mysql row to object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to convert a mysql row into an object with property => value

example

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blah...";
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $notification = new stdClass();
        //this is where I don't know what to do
        for every coloumn
            $notification->coloumn_name = value at that coloumn;
        //end of cluelessness   
        return $notification;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$query->result();
```

which always returns an stdClass object array..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$this->db->select('in_page_id,st_page_name,st_page_content');
$this->db->from('tbl_page_master');
$query = $this->db->get();

if($query->num_rows()>0)
{
    foreach($query->result() as $Row)
    {
        $arrCMS[$Row->in_page_id]    = array( 'cms_id'       => $Row->in_page_id,
                                              'cms_title'    => $Row->st_page_name,
                                              'cms_details'  => $Row->st_page_content
                                           );
    }
}
return $arrCMS;
```

Complete Dynamic Function can be written as follows.

```
function selectAll($table)
{
    $arrData    =   array();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $Row)
        {
           foreach($Row as $key=>$value)
           {
                $arr_element[$key]  = $value;
           }
           $arrData[] =   $arr_element;  
        }
    }
    return $arrData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$query->result()` in foreach loop of yours..

```
This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure.
```

[Also see this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) for more information...

Answer (score 0):

Use $query->result().
This would return a row at a time until you run out of row objects from the result.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    // Use $row as an object
    // echo $row->name;
}
```